# CreateRasterCatalog on the fly using ArcObject 10 .NET SDK

Tags: arcobjects

My debugger crashes without showing any error.

It crashes not even catches exception on the line:

```
rasterWorkspace.CreateRasterCatalog(catalogName, fields, "Shape", "Raster", "defaults");
```

Code snippet below:

```
CreateRasterCatalog(@"D:\TestfGDB\TestfGDB.gdb", "Test2");

    public void CreateRasterCatalog(string fGDBPath, string catalogName)
    {
        try
        {
            IRasterWorkspaceEx rasterWorkspace = OpenFileGDBWorkspace(fGDBPath);
            IFields fields = CreateField(null, null);
            IRasterCatalog rasterCatalog = rasterWorkspace.CreateRasterCatalog(catalogName, fields, "Shape", "Raster", "defaults");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a File geodatabase workspace. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">FGDB file path</param>
    protected IRasterWorkspaceEx OpenFileGDBWorkspace(string filePath)
    {
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
        IRasterWorkspaceEx workspaceEx = (IRasterWorkspaceEx)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(filePath, 0);
        return workspaceEx;
    }

    public IFields CreateField(ISpatialReference rasterSpatRef, ISpatialReference geoSpatRef)
    {
        IFields fields = new Fields();
        IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldsEdit)fields;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IField field = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.FieldClass();
        // create a user defined text field
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldEdit fieldEdit = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldEdit)field;

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "OBJECTID";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.AliasName_2 = "Sample Field Column";
        //fieldEdit.DefaultValue_2 = "test";
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Length_2 = 100;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);


        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Raster";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeRaster;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Name";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Metadata";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeBlob;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape_Length";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        // setup field properties
        fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape_Area";
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble;
        //fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        //fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        fieldsEdit.AddField(field);

        fields = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFields)fieldsEdit; 


        //// add OID field

        //fields.addField(createOIDField("ObjectID"));
        //// add NAME field
        //fields.addField(createNameField("name"));
        //// add RASTER field
        //fields.addField(createRasterField("raster", isByRef, rasterSpatRef));
        //// add SHAPE field
        //fields.addField(createShapeField("shape", geoSpatRef));

        return fields;
    }
```

Comment: Your line IFields fields = CreateField(null, null); is passing in NULL values, but your need to set the spatialrefence of your catalog. I think these need to be changed to spatialrefences for your code to work.

Comment: Thank you, passing spatial reference didn't solve the issue. However, figured using Geoprocessor is easier to create.

Comment: It would be good if you upload your solution and mark it solved  for others to benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue. Thanks. fGDBPath is full path of fGDB. i.e. C:\test\test.gdb

```
    public void CreateRasterCatalog(string fGDBPath, string catalogName)
    {
        Geoprocessor geoprocessor = new Geoprocessor();

        //Create an unmanaged raster catalog in the newly created personal GDB
        CreateRasterCatalog createRasterCatalog = new CreateRasterCatalog();

        createRasterCatalog.out_path = fGDBPath;
        createRasterCatalog.out_name = catalogName;
        createRasterCatalog.raster_management_type = "unmanaged";
        ISpatialReferenceFactory ipFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
        ISpatialReference xySpatialReference = ipFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984);
        createRasterCatalog.spatial_reference = xySpatialReference;
        createRasterCatalog.raster_spatial_reference = xySpatialReference;
        geoprocessor.Execute(createRasterCatalog, null);
    }
```